# Linq syntax for chaining query combinations

Tags: c#, linq

I have a few situations where I have combinations of selections and need to filter data (using EF in this case) based on what's selected. Is there cleaner way of writing the following rather than listing all of the combinations?

My initial attempt below seems overly complicated especially if the combinations grow any larger.

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Now.Date;
DateTime yesterday = today.AddDays(-1);
DateTime tomorrow = today.AddDays(1);

var query = db.Products.AsQueryable();
if (userSettings.DisplayYesterday && userSettings.DisplayToday && userSettings.DisplayTomorrow)
{
    query = query.Where(x => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.ListedTime) == yesterday || DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.ListedTime) == today || DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.ListedTime) == tomorrow);
}
else if (!userSettings.DisplayYesterday && userSettings.DisplayToday && userSettings.DisplayTomorrow)
{
    query = query.Where(x => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.ListedTime) == today || DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.ListedTime) == tomorrow);
}
else if (userSettings.DisplayYesterday && !userSettings.DisplayToday && userSettings.DisplayTomorrow)
{
    query = query.Where(x => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.ListedTime) == yesterday || DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.ListedTime) == tomorrow);
}
else if (userSettings.DisplayYesterday && userSettings.DisplayToday && !userSettings.DisplayTomorrow)
{
    query = query.Where(x => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.ListedTime) == yesterday || DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.ListedTime) == today);
}
else if (!userSettings.DisplayYesterday && !userSettings.DisplayToday && userSettings.DisplayTomorrow)
{
    query = query.Where(x => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.ListedTime) == tomorrow);
}
else if (!userSettings.DisplayYesterday && userSettings.DisplayToday && !userSettings.DisplayTomorrow)
{
    query = query.Where(x => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.ListedTime) == today);
}
else if (userSettings.DisplayYesterday && !userSettings.DisplayToday && !userSettings.DisplayTomorrow)
{
    query = query.Where(x => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.ListedTime) == yesterday);
}
else if (userSettings.DisplayYesterday && !userSettings.DisplayToday && !userSettings.DisplayTomorrow)
{
    query = query.Where(x => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.ListedTime) == yesterday);
}
else if (!userSettings.DisplayYesterday && !userSettings.DisplayToday && !userSettings.DisplayTomorrow)
{
    //  If nothing is selected then default to today
    query = query.Where(x => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.ListedTime) == today);
}

List<Products> productList = await query.ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can install LinqKit nuget package and use its `PredicateBuilder` (if for whatever reason you cannot\don't want to install third party package - you can implement similar functionality yourself). With `PredicateBuilder` you can do it like this:

```
// start with false, because building OR expression
// and false OR something is the same as just something
var condition = PredicateBuilder.New<Product>(false);
if (userSettings.DisplayYesterday)
    condition = condition.Or(x => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.ListedTime) == yesterday);
if (userSettings.DisplayToday)
    condition = condition.Or(x => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.ListedTime) == today);
if (userSettings.DisplayTomorrow)
    condition = condition.Or(x => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.ListedTime) == tomorrow);
query = query.Where(condition);
```

If you join multiple conditions with AND (and not OR like here), you don't need predicate builder, just chain `Where` calls:

```
if (someCondition)
    query = query.Where(x => x.SomeField == someValue);
if (anotherCondition)
    query = query.Where(x => x.SomeAnotherField == someAnotherValue);
```

Comment: Excellent, this is so much cleaner. Thank you.

Comment: @pathDongle I've updated answer a bit with a better solution (I think) for this partilcular case with dates.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't particularly looking for a date solution, it was just combinations. I fairly confident about dates and know DateTime.Now is correct in this situation. Thanks again.

Comment: @AntonínLejsek you are right, thanks. I deleted this part from answer.

Answer (score 0):

In Linq2Sql you can write

```
bool dispYesterday = userSettings.DisplayYesterday;
bool dispTomorrow = userSettings.DisplayTomorrow;
bool dispToday = userSettings.DisplayToday || !dispYesterday && !dispTomorrow;

query = query.Where(x =>
    dispYesterday && x.ListedTime.Date == yesterday
 || dispToday && x.ListedTime.Date == today
 || dispTomorrow && x.ListedTime.Date == tomorrow
);
```

It generates only conditions that are used thus making an efficient query. In EF you can write something simmilar, the generated sql query would be awkward and inefficient, but that is most of the code this framework generates anyway, so not a big deal.